# Integration vue component to MDX documentation in storybook 6 without create a story

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, storybook

I'm trying to make that for the component there is a separate playground and documentation (addon-docs 6.4.3) like here: https://consta-uikit.vercel.app/ But mdx doesn't see component in the mdx file. I'm using Vuetify2.6, Storybook6.4.
I have already tried adding various packages to my webpack config but it still doesn't want to load the vue component in mdx

```
// Button.mdx

import { ArgsTable } from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import { Button } from "../Button"

## Example title

<button text="test1"/>

<button text="test2"/>
```

```
// Button.stories.js
import Button from "../Button.vue";
import mdx from "./Получается так: Button.mdx";
export default {
  title: "Components/Basic/Button",
  component: Button,
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      page: mdx,
    },
  },
  argTypes: {
    size: {
      control: { type: "select" },
      options: ["S", "L"],
    },
    priority: {
      control: { type: "select" },
      options: ["primary", "outlined_blue", "outlined_red", "minimal"],
    },
    isLoading: {
      control: { type: "boolean" },
    },
    isDisabled: {
      control: { type: "boolean" },
    },
  },
};

const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  components: { Button },
  template: '<button @onClick="onClick" v-bind="$props" />',
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.storyName = "Playground";
Primary.args = {
  text: "Button",
  priority: "primary",
};
```

```
// .storybook/main.js
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require("vuetify-loader/lib/plugin");

module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  stories: [
    "../../src/**/*// .storybook/main.js
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require("vuetify-loader/lib/plugin");

module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  stories: [
    "../../src/**/*.stories.(js|jsx|mdx)",
    "../../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mdx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-docs",
    },
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.plugins.push(new VuetifyLoaderPlugin());
    return config;
  },
};.stories.(js|jsx|mdx)",
    "../../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mdx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-docs",
    },
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.plugins.push(new VuetifyLoaderPlugin());
    return config;
  },
};
```

[It seems like this(click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxH8N.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific use case, one that needed Storybook's MDX runtime to be told how to support Vue components. I've written a [Storybook addon](https://github.com/Sidnioulz/storybook-addon-vue-mdx) that lets you use Vue components in MDX for Storybook 7.

In the spirit of Stack Overflow, here's what the plugin does (which is how you would go about doing this yourself without third-party links):

- It registers a Storybook addon, so that it can integrate with Storybook's configuration override system
- It overrides Storybook's MDX options via the `mdxCompileOptions` config key
- In this override, it registers a custom JSX runtime that the MDX compiler will then use
- In that JSX runtime, it uses heuristics to determine if a node is likely to be a Vue node or a React / HTML one
- For Vue nodes, it wraps them through [Veaury](https://github.com/devilwjp/veaury), a project that maps Vue provide/inject with React context, provides React components that act as Vue app containers, etc.